# Можно ли говорить/писать "Ульянино заявление"?

Tags: склонение

"Ульянино заявление" - это правильный вариант? Или верный только "заявление Ульяны"?

Answer (score 1):

Это грамматически *возможный* вариант, но менее формальный и в некоторой степени фамильярный (уместный в узком кругу). Может подойти к случаю письменного заявления Ульяны, в меньшей степени - к случаю, если Ульяна что-то заявила вслух по какому-то поводу и в ещё меньшей степени, если она "заявилась" куда-либо.